# Can't update SalesReceipt in Quickbooks desktop

Tags: c#, quickbooks, nsoftware

I'm using QuickBooks Integrator from [/nSoftware](https://www.nsoftware.com/in/quickbooks) to integrate with QuickBooks Desktop

I'm trying to update an invoice and I don't get any errors but when I check in QuickBooks I see that nothing changed and it didn't actually get updated.

First I try to lookup the invoice based on the RefNumber and if it found an Invoice then I try to replace the Line Items and then i call the update method like this `existingInvoice.Update();`

Here's my code sample:

```
    public static List<Invoice> FindInvoice(string refNumber)
    {
        var invoicesSearch = new Objsearch
        {
            QueryType = ObjsearchQueryTypes.qtInvoiceSearch,
            RuntimeLicense = "MYLICENSEKEY",
            QBConnectionString = "MYCONNECTIONSTRINGTOREMOTECONNECTOR",
            SearchCriteria = new SearchCriteria
            {
                RefNumberContains = refNumber
            },
        };
        invoicesSearch.Search();
        var qbInvoiceList = invoicesSearch.Results.ToList();

        var invoiceObjList = new List<Invoice>();
        foreach (var inv in qbInvoiceList)
        {
            var newInv = new Invoice();
            newInv.QBResponseAggregate = inv.Aggregate;
            invoiceObjList.Add(newInv);
        }
        return invoiceObjList.FirstOrDefault();
    }



    public static void PutInvoice(Invoice invoice)
    {
        var existingInvoice = FindInvoice(invoice.RefNumber);
        if (existingInvoice != null)
        {
            existingInvoice.LineItems.Clear();
            existingInvoice.LineItems.AddRange(invoice.LineItems);

            existingInvoice.QBConnectionString = "MYCONNECTIONSTRINGTOREMOTECONNECTOR";
            existingInvoice.RuntimeLicense = RuntimeLicense;
            existingInvoice.QBXMLVersion = "12.0";

            existingInvoice.Update(); //this line 
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you step through this code with the debugger at what point do you first get an unexpected result?

Comment: @Crowcoder I don’t get any errors or any unexpected results. It just passes without any issues. That’s the funny part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the issue was that I was setting the `QBXMLVersion` the last thing before updating.

In order for the `Update()` to process successfully the `QBXMLVersion` needs to be set the first thing.

Here's an updated working example:

```
public static void PutInvoice(Invoice invoice)
{
    var existingInvoice = FindInvoice(invoice.RefNumber);
    if (existingInvoice != null)
    {
        existingInvoice.QBXMLVersion = "12.0";
        existingInvoice.RuntimeLicense = "MyRuntimeLicenseKey";
        existingInvoice.QBConnectionString = "MYCONNECTIONSTRINGTOREMOTECONNECTOR";

        existingInvoice.LineItems.Clear();
        existingInvoice.LineItems.AddRange(invoice.LineItems);

        existingInvoice.Update(); 
    }
}
```